# sched_setaffinity() unable to set the affinity mask

Tags: c++, linux

Hi I have this piece of code which is used to set and get a process's CPU affinity mask.
I am executing this on Linux and somehow after setting the affinity mask when I try to again get the affinity value to verify whether sched_setaffinity() works , I am getting the old value as given below. Can anyone suggest some way to resolve this?

Note: As in windows, there are PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION access right for SetProcessAffinityMask(). Are their any such kind of access rights needed in Linux as well to get the same functionality.

```
#include <sched.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>


bool getprocess_affinitymask(pid_t pid, unsigned long* pam) 
{
    if (sched_getaffinity(pid, sizeof(pam), (cpu_set_t*) pam) < 0) {
        perror("sched_getaffinity");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("pid %d's get affinity: %ld\n", pid, *pam);
    return 1;
}

bool setprocess_affinitymask(pid_t pid , unsigned long new_mask)
{
    if (sched_setaffinity(pid, sizeof(new_mask), (cpu_set_t *) &new_mask)) {
        perror("sched_setaffinity");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("pid %d's set affinity: %ld\n", pid, new_mask);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long mask;
    getprocess_affinitymask(getpid(), &mask);
    printf("Returned affinity: %ld\n", mask);
    setprocess_affinitymask(getpid(),15);
    getprocess_affinitymask(getpid(), &mask);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
pid 1's get affinity: 3
Returned affinity: 3
pid 1's set affinity: 15
pid 1's get affinity: 3
```

Comment: You're supposed to use the [`CPU_SET`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/CPU_SET.3.html) macros to setup your mask. Your `unsigned long` _may_ have a compatible layout, but why not try doing it properly?

Comment: The issue here is resolved. The mistake I did is storing the variable locally and taking the wrong mask as an input. Thanks  for the support .